# jQuery trigger event declared in tag with additional data

Tags: jquery, onchange, eventtrigger

I have a select with a change event handler:

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange="changedMySelect">
   <option value="test1">Test1</option>
   <option value="test2">Test2</option>
</select>
```

and

```
function changedMySelect(event, myParam1, myParam2) {
   alert(myParam1);
}
```

I would like to be able to trigger this event (declared in HTML) passing the additional params (myParam1, myParam2).

```
$("#mySelect").trigger("change", myParamValue1, myParamValue2);
```

However myParam1 is undefined, just like when the user clicks (which is expected). How to send the myParamValue1?

Ideally I should not move the onchange declared in HTML to Javascript (that is confirmed to work). We need to keep the onchange in the HTML, but we are able to modify it if necessary.

Comment: Inline bindings are only going to pass in what you tell them to pass in.  If you want to pass in something extra, you have to change it to `onchange="changedMySelect(whatever1, whatever2)"`

Comment: @Taplar Thank you, but then it says whatever1 is not defined. It is not defined indeed, it is only used when triggering via jQuery, not via user (interface).

Comment: Which reinforces that inline bindings are not the thing you should be using for your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the `onchange="something"` attribute, the function that is called will only receive what you put in the attribute. It will not get the event or anything else. So putting `onchange="changedMySelect(1, 2)"` would call your changedMySelect function with the arguments `1` and `2`.

In order for it to receive the event and other parameters, you will have handle the event through javascript instead. Also, jQuery's `trigger` needs the parameters as an array, not as separate parameters:

```js
function changedMySelect(event, myParam1, myParam2) {
   alert(myParam1 + ' ' + myParam2);
}

// You need to do this instead of using onselect in the HTML
$("#mySelect").on("change", changedMySelect);

$("#mySelect").trigger("change", ["param1", "param2"]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="mySelect">
   <option value="test1">Test1</option>
   <option value="test2">Test2</option>
</select>
```